# MATCH function - How to use a string as a range parameter

Tags: function, google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, notation

I need to create a generic formula to get a value from a `MATCH` command but I don't know exactly where the range of data is. I can not name the range.

The `MATCH` function does not work with a string as a range parameter.

Final result like this:

```
=MATCH("Risks";'SheetName'!B:B;0)
```

Using the code below.. considering A1 contents =SheetName

```
=MATCH("Risks"; A1&"!:B:B";0)
```

---

```
=MATCH("Risks"; Concatenate(A1;"!:B:B");0)
```

But doesn't work

Has anyone ever needed to use the `MATCH` command this way? Any workarounds?

Comment: `=MATCH("Risks";INDIRECT(A1&"!B:B");0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en&ref_topic=3105472) will help you get the job done.

The following supposes that you're specifying the sheet name in cell A1 and that the range you want to search is in column B of the specified sheet.

```
=MATCH("Risks",INDIRECT(A1&"!B:B"),0)
```

Comment: Make sense. Thank you.